# Rubberized wood coatings for decks: Can they be pressure-washed to clean them?

Tags: outdoor

Does anyone know whether rubberized wood coating products (for outdoor decks) can be pressure washed?  I mean, can they be pressure-washed to clean them, not to remove the coating?

Thanks -- I will look forward to any answers you might have. I am considering building a new deck and using one of these new rubberized products as my coating because outdoor wood simply does not last long here in Florida. My goal is to get maximum protection from rain/sun/rot and to have a deck which lasts thirty years without being refinished.  By the way, I am just DYI, not a professional contractor.

Answer (score 1):

Sure but understand two things: this product has had failures, meaning instances where it cracks and peels off. That has more to do with the contractor who put it on than the product, per se. Second, keep the tip head of the pressure washer "back" from the surface and begin in a section you can "test." Use a soap adapter with your pressure washer. The aggressiveness of the pressure washer is the psi but more so the distance to the surface. I have used pressure washing to both clean a deck and to strip off old coating by controlling the head distance to the surface.